# How to use ternary operator while pushing elements into the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to add the objects into the array based on the condition.

My expectation is to add two objects when the condition met but I am getting only the last object getting added (its element is missing).

```
const country = ‘USA’

citizenArray.push([
          {
            label: ‘Alex’,
            value: ’32’,
          },
          country === ‘USA’
            ? ({
                label: ‘John’,
                value: ’28’,
              },
              {
                label: ‘Miller’,
                value: ’40’,
              })
            : {
                label: ‘Marsh’,
                value: ’31’,
              },
        ]);
```

**The output I am getting:**

```
[{
            label: ‘Alex’,
            value: ’32’,
          },
{
                label: ‘Miller’,
                value: ’40’,
              }]
```

**Expected:**

```
[{
            label: ‘Alex’,
            value: ’32’,
          },
{
                label: ‘John’,
                value: ’28’,
              },
{
                label: ‘Miller’,
                value: ’40’,
              }]
```

Could somebody help me point out where I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `...(country === ‘USA’
            ? [{
                label: ‘John’,
                value: ’28’,
              },
              {
                label: ‘Miller’,
                value: ’40’,
              }]
            : [{
                label: ‘Marsh’,
                value: ’31’,
              }])`

Comment: That's how [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works.

Comment: I would not use curly quotes though...

Comment: Why do you tag with `ecmascript-5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript when you placed [comma-separated expressions within parathesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) it will execute each(left to right) and will return the result of last.

In your case `({ label: 'John', value: '28',}, { label: 'Miller', value: '40',})` results just the last object `{ label: ‘Miller’, value: ’40’, }` and adds to the array.

To make it work to use an array and then use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to add them.

```js
const country = 'USA';
const citizenArray = [];
citizenArray.push([{
    label: 'Alex',
    value: '32',
  },
  ...(country === 'USA' ? [{
    label: 'John',
    value: '28',
  }, {
    label: 'Miller',
    value: '40',
  }] : [{
    label: 'Marsh',
    value: '31',
  }])
]);

console.log(citizenArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Spread `...` operator

```
const myArray = [
  ...(condition1 ? [item1] : []),
  ...(condition2 ? [item2] : []),
  ...(condition3 ? [item3] : []),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use different logic like so:

```js
const country = "USA";
let citizenArray = [];
citizenArray.push([{ label: "Alex", value: "32" }, ...(country == "USA" ? [{ label: "John", value: "28" }, { label: "Miller", value: "40" }] : [{ label: "Marsh", value: "31" }])]);
console.log(citizenArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```